# Help understanding Bosch MP capacitors' several voltage ratings

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I've stumbled across a hoard of Bosch "MP" capacitors. I've not encountered these before and I'm having trouble finding any useful information on them. I gather they are Metallised Paper power capacitors. The text - as best as I can tell - reads:

```
BOSCH MP
Germany
Importee d'Allemagne
KO/MP 40/16 G 500/1
16uF (M)
500/750V--
oder {or}
220V~DB/330V~AB25
-25°C bis +70°C
tropenfest 
H 16/500K
DIN 41197
11/55
```

Way more data than I'm used to seeing on capacitors. The French and German text I'm OK with, but the numerous different voltages[?] highlighted are confusing. I don't want to do anything with this (or the others I've amassed) without knowing what I'm dealing with, or if indeed anything could be done.

[image]

Comment: "Bosch MP capacitors have not been around for about 30 years." Used probably as "starter capacitor". See this in "german" https://info.elektro-kahlhorn.de/bosch-mp-kondensatoren-ersatztypen/  where there are used ... Seems can be used with 220V ac (24h/24) or, 330 V ac with restricted time of functioning (2h/24) (not sure). See picture on site.

Comment: As a technically-focused architect the importance of datasheets to understanding any proposed or identifiable component or system isn't something I'm yet to learn. As a heritage conservation architect the frequent reality of dealing with components for which no published data is available, exists only on paper in private collections or in other languages necessitates drawing on the experience of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 220V~ DB / 330V~ AB25

**DB** stands for **D**auer**b**etrieb in German. It means "continuous operation".

**AB** stands for **A**ussetz**b**etrieb in German. It means "intermittent operation". And the number followed by AB indicates the duty cycle (Einschaltdauer) percentage of this intermittent operation.

So the voltages indicate the rated voltages for specific conditions:

- 220 Vac for continuous operation (100% duty-cycle)
- 330 Vac for up to 25% duty-cycle.

Comment: Yeah !  Ok, what about the picture in  my link where you find also ED/SD ? https://info.elektro-kahlhorn.de/wp-content/uploads/images/bosch-kondensator-1.jpg.webp

Comment: @Antonio51 Looking at `380V~AB20% ED / SD 24h` in the picture you supplied. ED means einschaltdauer (duty-cycle) as I already stated in my answer. SD means **S**piel**d**auer *(play time or operating time)*. So the whole statement means that the rated voltage is 380 Vac at 20% duty-cycle for an operating time of 24h a day.

Comment: Thanks. Very usefull "vintage" informations.